# Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mlflow

I have create a project of image classification using pickle file after load,i have served that model using docker and when i am trying to hit via postman on a port and localhost with image as a input,while proding image as input it gives me an error

```
This predictor only supports the following content types and formats: 
Types: ['text/csv', 'application/json', 'application/json-numpy-split']; 
Formats: ['pandas-records', 'pandas-split']. Got 'multipart/form-data; 
boundary=--------------------------181315360062149749865576'.
```

while providing input as numpy array it gives me error:
Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference.
.

```
my run.py
import pickletools
import model_service
import pickle
import mlflow
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import image_utils
import requests
from mlflow.models.signature import infer_signature
import tensorflow as tf
print('FIRST')

class ModelFunction:

        def __init__(self):
          self.model_service_obj = model_service.MlflowModelService() 

        def store_model(self,pickle_file): #pickle file will be in string format
          print('inside store_model...')
          infile = open(pickle_file,'rb+')
          model = pickle.load(infile) #load is used to load pickled data from a file-like object

          print('model pickle file loaded....')
          
  self.model_service_obj.saveModel(model,"keras","ImageClassification","preprocess.py")


        def load_model(self):
           self.model = self.model_service_obj.loadModel("ImageClassification","1")
           return self.model

class_labels=[
    "Plane",
    "Car",
    "Bird",
    "Cat",
    "Deer",
    "Dog",
    "Frog",
    "Horse",
    "Horse",
    "Boat",
    "Truck"
]

obj = ModelFunction()
obj.store_model("image_pickle.pkl")
model = obj.load_model()


img=image_utils.load_img("frog.jpg",target_size=(32,32))
image_to_test=image_utils.img_to_array(img)/255
list_of_images=np.expand_dims(image_to_test,axis=0)

#predict
results=model.predict(list_of_images)
single_result=results[0]

most_likely_class_index=int(np.argmax(single_result))
class_likelihood=single_result[most_likely_class_index]

class_label=class_labels[most_likely_class_index]

print("This is image is a {} - Likelihood: {:2f}".format(class_label,class_likelihood))

#########
MY MODEL SERVICE.PY
from asyncore import read
import logging
import pickle
import mlflow
import wrapper
import os
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy
import sys
from mlflow.models.signature import infer_signature
#Steps:
# 1.save Model
# 2.log model - set conda env , mlflow save model , mlflow log model 
# 3.register model
# 4.load model

class MlflowModelService:

   def saveModel(self,model,variant,readable_model_id,preprocess_file_path=None):
    print('inside storeModel of model service.......')
    readable_model_id = readable_model_id.replace("/","__$__")
    model_name = "Original-Model"
    with mlflow.start_run() as active_run:#mlflow work starts
        active_run = mlflow.active_run()
        mlflow.keras.save_model(model,model_name) #Save a scikit-learn model to a path on the local file system
        pyfunc_model_uri = self.logModel(readable_model_id,model_name,preprocess_file_path)
        self.registerModel(pyfunc_model_uri,readable_model_id)
        


   def loadModel(self,readable_model_id,version):
       model_uri = 'models:/' + str(readable_model_id) + "/" + version
       print('model uri of loadmodel=='+ model_uri)
       self.model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)
       return self.model

  
   def logModel(self,readable_model_id,model_name,preprocess_file_path):
      artifacts = {
         "Original_Model":model_name,
         "Original-model":preprocess_file_path
         }
      model_data = mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
             artifact_path=str(readable_model_id),
             python_model= wrapper.Model_Wrapper(),
             artifacts=artifacts,
             code_path= ["wrapper.py"]
             #signature=infer_signature
        )
      return model_data.model_uri


   def registerModel(self,model_uri,readable_model_id):
        model_data = mlflow.register_model(model_uri,readable_model_id)

#####
my wrapper.py
import mlflow
import os
import importlib.util
import preprocess
import tensorflow as tf
class Model_Wrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Directory ----> ",os.getcwd())
        

    def load_context(self,context):
        self.model=mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(context.artifacts["Original_Model"])

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        print ("Invoking predict with \n", model_input)

        if "Preprocessor_file" in context.artifacts.keys():
            spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("preprocess", context.artifacts["Preprocessor_file"])

            preprocessor = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            spec.loader.exec_module(preprocessor)

            if "user_data" in context.artifacts.keys():
                os.chdir(context.artifacts["user_data"])

            model_input = preprocessor.preprocess(model_input)
            return self.model.predict(model_input)
```

I am using pickle file of ImageClassification model